# Arduino-Python Serial Communication HC-SR04

Tags: python, arduino, serial-communication

I'm trying to measure distance using HC-SR04 then writing it to python's monitor. The first output that python shows is true but second and the other outputs looks like python read two parts of the distance value. I think, i am having some timing issues but i tried to change delays in two of them and that didn't work.

When I run the code output looks like this:

```
 C:\Users\mobyr\PycharmProjects\1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/mobyr/Desktop/mesafeolc.py
distance 2.18 m
distance 
2. m
distance 18
 m

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I get the true values on
Arduino's Serial Monitor

```
2.18
2.19
2.18
2.17
2.17
2.17
2.18
2.20
2.17
```

Python Codes:

```
import serial
import time
arduino = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)



def Measure():
    distance = arduino.read(4)
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("distance "+distance+" m")
    return float(distance)


while True:
    output = Measure()
    if output > 5:
        break
```

Arduino Codes:

```
const int echo_pin = 9;
const int trig_pin = 10;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(echo_pin, INPUT);
  pinMode(trig_pin, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  double period, distance;
  digitalWrite(trig_pin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trig_pin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trig_pin, LOW);
  period = pulseIn(echo_pin, HIGH);
  distance = (period / 2) / 29.1;
  distance = distance / 100; //to convert cm to m
  delay(500);
  Serial.println(distance);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `distance = arduino.read(4)` reads 4 chars, but the output you are after is actually 5 chars, cause the linebreak is also counted as a char.

I would recommend using `distance = arduino.readline()` instead, then you can handle values of any size.

Comment: Thank you. `distance = arduino.readline()` this worked for me.